# Is it better to force actions in the main thread or to use synchronization?

Tags: ios, multithreading, synchronization, atomic

Say I have a method that starts a download for an object, which may be called from any thread, but I want to make sure that the download is unique, that is, I won't start another download for the same object if there is already one.

Is it better to force the method to perform on the main thread to ensure data consistency (knowing the download will be asynchronous anyway)?

```
- (void)download
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (isDownloading == NO) {
            // Some preparation
            isDownloading = YES;
            // Launch asynchronous download
        }
    });
}
```

or to use a blocking synchronization mechanism?

```
- (void)download
{
    @synchronize(self) {
        if (isDownloading == NO) {
            // Some preparation
            isDownloading = YES;
            // Launch asynchronous download
        }
    });
}
```

or to use an operation like `OSAtomicCompareAndSwap` on the `isDownloading` ivar?

Are there differences in term of performances? What would be the best strategy?

Comment: I've deleted my answer.  As you've pointed out, I was incorrect (I misread  a few things).  The only real difference between the two options is that if your main thread winds up blocking on something, that'll provide an additional source of slowdown.  I'd go with the `@synchronize` version on policy, but it shouldn't be a big deal one way or another.